# UIAlertView does not appear if requestAccessToEntityType fails

Tags: objective-c, calendar, uialertview

i'm making an app that adds events to the default calendar but i found a problem. This is the code used to make the app access to the calendar:

```
// create eventStore object.
EKEventStore *eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];

if([eventStore respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAccessToEntityType:completion:)])

{
    [eventStore requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error)
     {
         if(granted)
         {
             // create an instance of event with the help of event-store object.
             EKEvent *event = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventStore];

             // set the title of the event.
             event.title = @"Event";


             event.startDate = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:86400]; 

             event.endDate = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:90000]; 

             // set the calendar of the event. - here default calendar
             [event setCalendar:[eventStore defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];

             // store the event using EventStore.
             NSError *err;
             [eventStore saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&err];

         }
         else {

            UIAlertView *warningAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"No permission to access!" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [warningAlert show];
         }

     }];
}
```

I supposed that if i got to general>privacy and set the access to calendar to "NO", whenever i click on the button that makes the action listed before, the program should skip in the "else" (founding the bool as false) that creates the alertView. But when i try this the program crashes not letting me do anything and if i press the home-button and then re-enter the app an empty alertView will appear (no title or message).

How can i solve this? i put the alertView in the wrong place?

Added info: this function is on a button that i click every time i mean to an event.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried showing the alert in main thread..

```
if (granted)
{
  ....
}
else {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
       UIAlertView *warningAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"No permission to access!" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
       [warningAlert show];
    });
}
```

Requesting permissions from user won't happen in main thread. You can do your UI stuff (Alert) by getting to the main thread. Hope it helps..